# Using bower with plugins that need AMD

Tags: plugins, requirejs, amd, bower

I have a trying to use Bower.io with my RequireJS AMD project but I'm pretty new to it. I have a plugin in my `bower.json` file thats like

`"jquery-ui-touch-punch": "https://github.com/furf/jquery-ui-touch-punch.git",`

but the problem is that this file is not wrapped in AMD - so it errors. I can manually edit the file to wrap it - but that makes no sense for the purposes of using bower. Is there some resource I can use or a way I can make this wrap inside `requireJS` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> shim: Configure the dependencies, exports, and custom initialization
>   for older, traditional "browser globals" scripts that do not use
>   define() to declare the dependencies and set a module value.

http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#config-shim

Comment: thanks :) will that work with bower ? i noticed that bower requires the surrounding `require()` or `define()` code in the plugin itself ?